# Splunk REST API - Specify relative time range for alert

Tags: rest, splunk

I want to create an alert using Splunk's REST API. I want the alert to get events which happened in the last two minutes. How can I do that?

This is my alert so far:

```
curl -k -u admin:password https://my.company:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches \
  -d name=test7 \
  --data-urlencode output_mode='json' \
  --data-urlencode actions='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.digest_mode='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.expires='24h' \
  --data-urlencode alert.managedBy='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.severity='3' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.fields='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.period='5m' \
  --data-urlencode alert.track='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert_comparator='greater than' \
  --data-urlencode alert_condition='' \
  --data-urlencode alert_threshold='10' \
  --data-urlencode alert_type='number of events' \
  --data-urlencode allow_skew='0' \
  --data-urlencode cron_schedule='*/2 * * * *' \
  --data-urlencode description='' \
  --data-urlencode disabled='0' \
  --data-urlencode displayview='' \
  --data-urlencode is_scheduled='1' \
  --data-urlencode is_visible='1' \
  --data-urlencode max_concurrent='1' \
  --data-urlencode realtime_schedule='1' \
  --data-urlencode restart_on_searchpeer_add='1' \
  --data-urlencode run_n_times='0' \
  --data-urlencode run_on_startup='0' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_priority='default' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_window='0' \
  --data-urlencode search='sourcetype="auth" failed'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters you are looking for in [Splunk's documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/RESTREF/RESTsearch#saved.2Fsearches) are `dispatch.earliest_time` and `dispatch.latest_time`.

Here is your request with the added parameters. It will look for events during the last 2 minutes:

```
curl -k -u admin:password https://my.company:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches \
  -d name=test7 \
  --data-urlencode output_mode='json' \
  --data-urlencode actions='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.digest_mode='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.expires='24h' \
  --data-urlencode alert.managedBy='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.severity='3' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.fields='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.period='5m' \
  --data-urlencode alert.track='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert_comparator='greater than' \
  --data-urlencode alert_condition='' \
  --data-urlencode alert_threshold='10' \
  --data-urlencode alert_type='number of events' \
  --data-urlencode allow_skew='0' \
  --data-urlencode cron_schedule='*/2 * * * *' \
  --data-urlencode description='' \
  --data-urlencode disabled='0' \
  --data-urlencode displayview='' \
  --data-urlencode is_scheduled='1' \
  --data-urlencode is_visible='1' \
  --data-urlencode max_concurrent='1' \
  --data-urlencode realtime_schedule='1' \
  --data-urlencode restart_on_searchpeer_add='1' \
  --data-urlencode run_n_times='0' \
  --data-urlencode run_on_startup='0' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_priority='default' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_window='0' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.earliest_time='-2m' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.latest_time='now' \
  --data-urlencode search='sourcetype="auth" failed'
```